# Which "C# Experimental language feature" is this?

Tags: c#, language-features, c#-6.0

In the example below, Resharper shows "C# Experimental language feature" tooltip on the first curly bracket. I've checked the new features of C# 6.0 but didn't come across a similar one. What is the referred experimental feature?

```
 class Class1
 {
     { // <= C# Experimental language feature
     }
 }
```

Note: It is an error for .Net Framework 4.5 compiler.

> "Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This *was* for [Primary Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx), a feature which has now been [cut from C#6](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820).

Comment: Sad days. F# FTW I guess until C#7 and (hopefully) record types.

Answer (score 0):

On November 12, 2014 Microsoft announced the release of `Visual Studio 2015` on the day of `Visual Studio Connect() from New York, USA` where they announced many new features as well as enhancements with `C# 6.0`. So we should understand that a `Primary Constructor` is not applicable with `C# 6.0` but we can do the same thing using `Auto Implemented Properties Initializers`.

Basically a Primary Constructor is a feature of C# that was announced with `Visual Studio 2014`. But now it has been removed from `Visual Studio 2015` Preview. So  in C# 6.0 it's not possible to use a primary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use this if you click on your project, and go to the Properties pane and select C# Language Level to Experimental.